Showing that Exponentials of the Subobject Classifier are Power Objects
I'm trying to show (directly) that an exponential $\Omega^X$ (where $\Omega$ is a subobject classifier) is a power object of $X$; I can easily see why this is true, and it seems like it should be easy to prove, but I'm struggling to find the appropriate mono $∈_X$ to use. If anyone could give me a hint, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Edit: This question has been well answered and it's now clear that the main source of confusion was an attempt on my part to minimise the requirements placed on the subobject classifier. So, for context, this question was asked without appreciation for the requirement that our category have finite limit, using the diagrammatic definition of the subobject classifier.

The power object of $X$ is a representation of the functor $Sub(- \times X)$. We have natural bijections $$\hom(T,\Omega^X) = \hom(T \times X, \Omega) = Sub(T \times X),$$ so we are done.
The universal element is constructed - as always - by applying this to the identity of the universal object. So we take $T = \Omega^X$ and apply the bijection to the identity, the result by definition is the subobject of $\Omega^X \times X$ that corresponds to the evaluation morphism to $\Omega$.

Hey Martin, thanks for the answer! Am I right in thinking that the second bijection only exists given the existance of certain pullbacks (so that every morphism into the classifier is characteristic of some subobject)? Is this a necessary condition for the fact to hold? Obviously this is not an issue working in a topos but the fact that this hypothesis is often left implicit is probably the reason it was hard for me to put together myself.

This is the definition of the subobject classifier. I don't use anything else. Morphisms from A into that subobject classifier correspond to subobjects of A by the very definition.

In order for Sub to be a functor in the first place, you do require the existence of pullbacks at least where one of the maps is monic; and Sub being a functor is a prerequisite to the definitions both of subclassifier object and of power object.

Exactly. $~~~~~$

You want a subobject of $X \times \Omega^{X}$.  By the universal property of the subobject classifier, such a subobject is equivalently a morphism $X \times \Omega^{X} \to \Omega$.  But the definition of the exponential object $\Omega^{X}$ gives you a morphism of precisely this kind, the evaluation map.

Hi John, appreciate the direct answer. As I've asked Martin Brandenburg above, can you confirm that this argument relies on the assumption that assignment of subobjects to morphisms into the classifier is surjective (which I believe relies on the existance of pullbacks of the true point of Ω)? I suppose the alternative is that the necessary pullback along the evaluation morphism always exists.

@CVAstley oh, yes, I was assuming that all limits exist; this assumption is often (even usually?) part of the definition of the subobject classifier and power object. One could in principle weaken them, but it might be more convenient to handle more general situations on a case-by-case basis.

For what it is worth, there is a "brute-force" proof from definitions given for the result (as Theorem 114), starting on p. 209 of my notes Introducing Category Theory which you can download from https://www.logicmatters.net/categories. (This spells out the proof idea indicated by @JohnDougherty.)

Appreciate the link Peter. It took me a minute to realise that I've used your notes once or twice before, to great effect if memory serves. I have a lot of admiration for this PDF :)
